# SQL + ASP.Net Efficient paging

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

My method of paging is inefficient as it calls the same query twice therefore doubling the query time. I currently call the 1 query that joins about 5 tables together with XML search querys to allow for passing List from ASP.net.. then I need to call exactly the same query except with a Count(row) to get the amount of records

For Example (I have removed bits to make it easier to read)

Main Query:

```
WITH Entries AS (
  select row_number() over (order by DateReady desc)
  as rownumber, Columns...,

 from  quote

 join geolookup as Pickup on pickup.geoid = quote.pickupAddress

 where 
     quote.Active=1
     and //More 
 )
 select * from entries 
 where Rownumber between (@pageindex - 1) * @pagesize + 1 and @pageIndex * @pageSize
 end
```

Count Query:

```
 select count(rowID)        
 from  quote

 join geolookup as Pickup on pickup.geoid = quote.pickupAddress

 where 
     quote.Active=1
     and //More 
 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could select the results of your big query into a temp table, then you could query this table for the row number and pull out the rows you need.

To do this, add (after your select statement and before the from)

```
INTO #tmpTable
```

Then reference your table as `#tmpTable`

---

```
select row_number() over (order by DateReady desc)  
  as rownumber, Columns...,  
into #tmpTable

 from  quote  

 join geolookup as Pickup on pickup.geoid = quote.pickupAddress  

 where   
     quote.Active=1  
     and //More   
 )  

 SELECT @Count = COUNT(*) FROM #tmpTable

 select * from #tmpTable  
 where Rownumber between (@pageindex - 1) * @pagesize + 1 and @pageIndex * @pageSize
```

Comment: Why do you need the tmptable?  - Could you not just put the count(*) in the first select so each row has the count in it?

Comment: No, because to do a `COUNT(*)` you have to do a `GROUP BY` aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

You can set an output parameter which will hold the number of rows from the first query.

You could do something like

```
WITH Entries AS (
  select row_number() over (order by DateReady desc)
  as rownumber, Columns...,

 from  quote

 join geolookup as Pickup on pickup.geoid = quote.pickupAddress

 where 
     quote.Active=1
    and //More 
 )

select @rowcount = max(rownumber) from entries

 select * from entries 
 where Rownumber between (@pageindex - 1) * @pagesize + 1 and @pageIndex * @pageSize
```

Hope this helps

Comment: You can't call a CTE twice, so the last statement will fail.

Comment: ahh ok, so as per your suggestion you would need to fill a temp table with the results before selecting from it, that way you can select from it twice.. makes sense.